# Getting an "UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY" while using "tsd" command

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to use the below **tsd** command to install angular type definition files in my project.

`tsd install angular --resolve --save`

**TypeScript Version:**  2.3.4

However when I try to do that, I'm getting the below error.

```
[ERR!] node : v7.8.0
[ERR!] tsd  : 0.6.5
[ERR!] Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
[ERR!] CODE : UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY
[ERR!] unable to get local issuer certificate
```

I've tried setting the `strict-ssl` to `false` using `npm` and even tried executing `npm cache clean` command, But no luck though.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't use `tsd` anymore. The project is deprecated and not maintained. Just use `npm install @types/angular`.

## More

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd/issues/149

Comment: Thanks! Mr.Typescript! :-)